# Search cell for specific text, then, copy and paste that text into another cell

Tags: excel

I hope its understandable, here is an example where column2 is to pick out specific words (Chicken, cheese)

Column1

Chicken, pasta 
lemon, oregano

Column2

Chicken

Column1

peas, corn, 
cheese, chicken

Column2

cheese, chicken

Comment: No, I'm sorry, this is icomprehensible. Please edit your question to describe: input, desired output, what you have tried to obtain this output, and how exactly this did not succeed.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can sort of do it with the formula:

```
=MID(IF(ISERROR(SEARCH("chicken",A1)),"",", Chicken") & IF(ISERROR(SEARCH("cheese",A1)),"",", Cheese"),3,999)
```

It works by searching for each word in your Column A value and adding that to a string if it is found (i.e. if `SEARCH` doesn't give an error). The `MID` is to get rid of the extra separator (given we don't know how many matches we will get)

But it is horrible (hard-coded values and if you grow it, it becomes much longer) and doesn't quite give you the result (second example gives "Chicken, Cheese" not "cheese, chicken")

But, as @Jean-Francois says, the request is pretty vague :-)